# Are there limits to the number of new macros or commands in TeX/LaTeX

Tags: macros, memory

Is there a maximum number of new definitions such as

```
\def\myNewDefA{foo}
\def\myNewDefB{bar}
...
\newcommand\myNewMacroA{foo}
\newcommand\myNewMacroB{bar}
```

one can have in a document typeset with pdflatex?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

TeX has lots of memory limitations.

The following TeX file for iniTeX tests some of them:

```
% test.tex
% iniTeX
% preamble
\tracingstats=1
\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2  
\countdef\i=255
\countdef\m=100
\chardef\l=1
\def\e{}
\i=0
\def\n{%
  \ifnum\i<\m
    \advance\i\l%
    \expandafter\let\csname x\the\i\endcsname\e
  \else
    \let\n\end
  \fi
  \n
}
% main
\m=0 % number of macro definitions
\n
% end of test.tex
```

The test file defines `\m` macros of the form `\x1`, `\x2`, `\x3` etc.
They are defined via `\let` that does not take memory for the definition,
because this is shared with the macro (the empty macro `\e` in this case).

After running (e.g. `tex --ini test`) the file `test.log` contains a short memory statistics.

Some examples:

### `\m=0`

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4 strings out of 498654
 30 string characters out of 6225568
 1060 words of memory out of 5000000
 322 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7 words of font info for 0 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 1i,0n,0p,54b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

### `\m=100000`

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 100004 strings out of 498654
 588925 string characters out of 6225568
 1074 words of memory out of 5000000
 100322 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7 words of font info for 0 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,54b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

### `\m=498654`

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 498654 strings out of 498654
 3379475 string characters out of 6225568
 1074 words of memory out of 5000000
 498972 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7 words of font info for 0 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,54b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

`pdftex --ini test` already fails with:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=497943].
```

### Number of strings (`max_strings`)

TeX Live 2013 uses `max_strings=500000` in `texmf.cnf`. Some strings are preoccupied (names of primitives, ...). The macro names, defined in the test file, use short one character/letter command names that are not stored as strings. Strings are stored as indexes to the memory pool.

The number of strings can be increased, e.g. (bash):

```
$ max_strings=1000000 tex --ini test
```

But then the limitation of the hash table is hit (`\m=800000`):

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [hash size=615000].
```

### Hash table size (`hash_extra`)

Each command name is also stored in a hash table for fast access.
Its size `15000` can be increased by `hash_extra` (`600000` in TL 2013).

```
$ max_strings=1000000 hash_extra=1000000 tex --ini test
```

now works for `\m=800000`:

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 800004 strings out of 998654
 5488925 string characters out of 6225568
 1074 words of memory out of 5000000
 800322 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+1000000
 7 words of font info for 0 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,54b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

### Pool size (`pool_size`)

The memory where the string characters are actually stored is the string pool. Its size is also limited (default for `pool_size` in TL 2013 is `6250000`).

With `\m=1500000` the following command

```
$ max_strings=1600000 hash_extra=1600000 pool_size=16000000 tex --ini test
```

succeeds with

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1500004 strings out of 1598654
 10888926 string characters out of 15975568
 1076 words of memory out of 5000000
 1500322 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+1600000
 7 words of font info for 0 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,54b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

### Main memory (`main_memory`)

With non-trivial definitions also the main memory is used. The following line

```
\expandafter\edef\csname x\the\i\endcsname{\the\i}%
```

defines the macros `\x1`, `\x2`, `\x3` with a definition text that contains the number.

Result for `\m=1000000` and

```
$ max_strings=1600000 hash_extra=1600000 pool_size=16000000 main_memory=10000000 tex --ini test

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1000004 strings out of 1598654
 6888926 string characters out of 15975568
 7889966 words of memory out of 10000000
 1000322 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+1600000
 7 words of font info for 0 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 3i,0n,0p,62b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

But the main memory cannot be increased indefinitely, e.g. using `main_memory=15000000` results in an internal fatal error:

```
Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14
```

### Summary

TeX was written in a time, where memory was very limited and expensive and the computers were very slow. Therefore Knuth has written its own memory management with fixed sized tables that do not dynamically grow, if the maximum size is reached. Some table sizes can be increased *before* the TeX run. But some implementation limits remain.

### LuaTeX

LuaTeX has rewritten the core of TeX, thus some limitations are gone. The latest example with `\m=1500000` runs with

```
$ max_strings=1600000 hash_extra=1600000 luatex --ini test
```

and uses the following memory (0.76.0):

```
Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 1500013 strings out of 1598958
 500,14696376 words of node,token memory allocated
 58 words of node memory still in use:
    nodes
   avail lists: 2:1,6:1
 1500335 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+1600000
 0 fonts using 0 bytes
 3i,0n,0p,61b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
```

Comment: I'm writing a textbook for aerospace engineers with many calculation examples. The way I managed to typeset calculation results is based on [this talk](http://www.guitex.org/home/images/meeting2012/slides/presentazione_demarco_guitmeeting_2012.pdf). I use mostly TeX-style definitions like: \def\myAltitudeMT{5000}. So, as I understand your answer, if I introduce, say, 1000 new macro definitions I should be safe with pdflatex.

Comment: @agodemar: 1000 macro definitions are not much of a problem. But if your book has 10000 pages, each page 100 labels, then you would already have a million macro definitions for the labels.

Comment: @agodemar: Modern TeX installations have default memory limits that should be hard to hit with these kind of documents; _iff_ you meet them you easily extend the limits. Don't worry, it will work. :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for your great response. I want to know is there any way to free TeX memory by removing some of old defined macros?!